# What is the difference between "dry run" and "rehearsal"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I saw a phrase "dry run".
I am wondering if there is any difference between "dry run" and "rehearsal".

I looked it up.
Its meaning is the same as the term "rehearsal".
My question is that are they interchangable.
Sorry, I don't have any example.

May I have your confirmation?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You could say that a ***dry run*** is ***a type of rehearsal***. Specifically, the type of rehearsal where you run through a show without stopping to actually work on issues, for the sake of testing where the ensemble's cohesiveness and preparedness is.

Rehearsal is a time set aside to rehearse, or, to work on a specific set of pieces, a show, or some other event. Sometimes, a rehearsal is involved in the sense of working on issues with the group, and addressing questions and concerns. On the opposite is a very hands-off type of rehearsal, which is the ***dry run***. This is the rehearsal that can happen at specific determined checkpoints, to make sure that things are ready, or to assess all the issues at once before settling on a plan to address them in full before performance time.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference that I can think of is that a *dry run* may not have a pre-defined outcome, whereas a *rehearsal* (of a play or a wedding ceremony, say) usually does have pre-defined course and outcome. A dry run of a military action may well have an unexpected outcome (but it is still a *dry run*).

As you say, the dictionary definitions are very much the same.